# How much faster is memory (RAM) compared to SSD for random access?

Tags: memory, ssd, performance

I read from SO that [memory is 100,000 faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371400/how-much-faster-is-the-memory-usually-than-the-disk) than (mechanical) HDD in random access. But the answers there do not speak to SSD drives.

SSDs are different from HDD in construction. Does anyone know a rough estimate how much faster is RAM than SSD drives?

Comment: HDD speeds are currently up to 200MB/sec (sequantial), SSD speeds are up to 3200MB/sec. So in theory the difference would be up to 16x less. It is comparing apples to oranges though, SSDs act differently, so raw speed comparisions would be flawed.

Comment: 100.000 times faster is incorrect. Its a lot faster, yes, but 100.000 is an arbitrairy number. SSD disks are basically memory moduies in a harddisk container, though they are slower than actual memory in order to allow the costs to be lower. So they are still pretty fast.

Comment: Another prematurely closed question.  Well done @LPChip and everyone else.  Of course it's not opinion based.  They have finite and measureable differences.  This place is getting rather ugly from the web.  Always landing here on great questions that have been closed.  It just looks tacky

Comment: HERE ARE SOME BENCHMARKS: using SSD compared to a RAMdisk, the tests suggest that SSD is 10-15% as fast for writing and 1-5% as fast for reading... If you compare the numbers, you will see that SSD is 20-80 times slower than RAM on these real-world enthusiast PC's. https://www.google.com/search?q=SSD+vs+ramdisk+tests&tbm=isch

Answer (score 11):

See https://www.quora.com/Is-the-speed-of-SSD-and-RAM-the-same:

> Flash Memory is considerably slower than DRAM, and the way they are
>   used by operating systems is very different.
>
> A typical DRAM has a transfer rate of approximately 2-20GB/s, whereas
>   typical SSDs have a transfer rate of 50MB-200MB/s. So it's one to two
>   orders of magnitude slower.
>
> Furthermore, the way it's used is very different. DRAM is far more
>   flexible and is truly random access -- any word, any time. By
>   comparison, flash writes have to erase an entire block at a time
>   before writing to it; and there are other problems that need to be
>   dealt with such as wear leveling and bad blocks.

Comment: The new ssd's getting pretty fast one example is: Intel's new P3608 Series PCIe SSD, The drive has a sequential read/write speed of up to 5,000MBps (5Gbps) and 3,000MBps (3Gbps), respectively.

Comment: punchline - "any word, any time" :))

Comment: Seems like RAMs have also gone tremendously more fast than the numbers mentioned in this answer (so have SSDs as mentioned in a previous comment). My source: https://youtu.be/o54YMz8zvCY?t=1399

Comment: With a (pro-) *consumer* grade SSD we're already at 7.2 GB/s at the time of writing. PCIe v4 with 4 lanes and a lot of fast flash.

Answer (score 6):

Run [memtest86](https://www.google.se/?gfe_rd=cr&safe=off#safe=off&q=memtest86), it displays numbers indicating memory read/write speed.

FWIW an Intel Atom 330 based mini-computer I currently have standing here says "1927MB/s" for the main RAM.
L1 Cache is 3748MB/s, L2 Cache is 3095MB/s, there is no L3 Cache.

These speeds will vary with CPU and computer design.

A google on ["SSD disk speed"](https://www.google.se/search?q=SSD%20disk%20speed) will tell you numbers to compare with; expect anything from speeds similar to fast HDD's (100-150MB/s, slow SSD) and up.

Answer (score 0):

DRAM is much faster than any SSD or other solid state storage device. Generally, you can put it to be at least 5-10 times faster, depending on frequency, generation and the SSD you are comparing it with. SRAM is even faster than DRAM, at least a few times more.

To get some sort of comparison, you can set up a RAMdisk on the target machine and then benchmark both the SSD and the RAM. You can get some information on this here:

http://www.pcworld.com/article/260918/how_to_supercharge_your_pc_with_a_ram_disk.html